# free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000f45160 ***

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error, memcpy, memset

I've read about this error occurring due to freeing a non-allocated pointer (*e.g.* double-freeing a pointer) but in my case the offending line looks like this:

```
memset(data + prev_bytes, 0, sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes);
```

When I comment this out, the error goes away. So, I figure I must be writing past the buffer I allocated, but I don't see how. I added some debugging output before the offending line, like so:

```
cout << ">                 address of `data`: " << static_cast<void*>(data) << endl;
cout << ">                      `prev_bytes`: " << prev_bytes << endl;
cout << ">    address at `data + prev_bytes`: " << static_cast<void*>(data + prev_bytes) << endl;
cout << ">                            `size`: " << size << endl;
cout << "> `sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes`: " << (sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes) << endl;
memset(data + prev_bytes, 0, sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes);
```

And the output is:

```
>                 address of `data`: 0xf450f0
>                      `prev_bytes`: 32
>    address at `data + prev_bytes`: 0xf45170
>                            `size`: 16
> `sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes`: 32
free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000f45160 ***
```

To give a little context, `data` is an array of integers, and I want to keep the first `prev_bytes` of this array intact, while clearing the rest, *i.e.* setting to zeroes.

To achieve this, I'm `memset`ing starting at the `data` pointer offset by `prev_bytes`, and writing a number of zeroes. That number being: the `size` of this (dynamically allocated) array, multiplied by `sizeof(int)` (presumably 4 bytes), minus `prev_bytes`.

I just don't see how I could be writing past what I've allocated. In case more code is needed, here's the full functions. It just extends an array to double its size.

```
void extend(int*& data, int& size, int& used) {
    int resize_factor = 2;
    int* new_buffer = new int[size * resize_factor];
    int  prev_bytes = sizeof(int) * size;
    memcpy(new_buffer, data, prev_bytes);
    delete [] data;
    data = new_buffer;
    size *= resize_factor;
    cout << ">                 address of `data`: " << static_cast<void*>(data) << endl;
    cout << ">                      `prev_bytes`: " << prev_bytes << endl;
    cout << ">    address at `data + prev_bytes`: " << static_cast<void*>(data + prev_bytes) << endl;
    cout << ">                            `size`: " << size << endl;
    cout << "> `sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes`: " << (sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes) << endl;
    memset(data + prev_bytes, 0, sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes);
}
```

Comment: I haven't spotted the error, but I've noticed `used` isn't actually used. I assume `size` refers to the array's capacity and that the number of  bytes to copy should depend on `used` instead.

Comment: Does `sizeof(int)  == sizeof(void*)` ? The reason I'm asking:

`int  prev_bytes = sizeof(int) * size;`

and then:
`memset(data + prev_bytes, 0, sizeof(int) * size - prev_bytes);`

Are you sure you're getting the right addr passed to memset?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - That's an accident actually. I used to check whether I needed to extend the array (i.e. `used` was going to exceed `size`) here, but now I do it outside this function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array `data` is treated as an array of integers. By using pointer arithmetic `data + prev_bytes` is actually being interepreted as `data + prev_bytes * sizeof(int)` and you overflow the buffer.

You can see that by comparing the address of `data` with the address of `data + prev_bytes`. It's 128 bytes greater, instead of 32.

I think it's because you are casting after you add. Try instead to cast before you add.

```
static_cast<void*>(data) + prev_bytes
```

Comment: Instead of casting the pointer, switch `prev_bytes` to `prev_items`. It simplifies the code a lot.